# parsing large json data in and out of models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework, json

I have a large json server response which nests models in models. I have no way of making the server rest based. I need to parse the json tree into collections and collections within collections. I would then like to export the backbone models in the same json structure to the server after modification.

i have a collection called sections, and using this method to nest the questions collection within each section model:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

the top level of the json response is the array of sections so i have been able to pass that directly to the sections collection, I have then used the initialize method to parse out the child questions and then deleted them from the attributes. But this means i dont get the model.questions returned in any toJSON on the sections collection.

```
SCC.Models.Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var questions = this.get('questions');
        this.questions = new SCC.Collections.Questions(questions);
        delete this.attributes.questions;

    }
});

SCC.Collections.Sections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SCC.Models.Section
});

SCC.Sections = new SCC.Collections.Sections();
//imagine window.SectionData is the server response
SCC.Sections.reset(window.SectionData);
```

Hopefully I am clear. Let me if you need more info.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited number of nested models which are under you control and are not subject to frequent change, the easy way is to override `toJSON()` method for your models that have nested collections:

```
SCC.Models.Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var questions = this.get('questions');
        this.questions = new SCC.Collections.Questions(questions);
        delete this.attributes.questions;
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
        json.questions = this.questions.toJSON()
        return json
    }
});
```

However, if you have a lot of nested collections which are subject to change, more abstract way would be nice.

I can think for example of storing all nested collections in model's special property (say `nestedCollections`) and then monkey patching `Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON` so that it will always parse all nestedCollections and add them to JSON object before returning it.

Another way would be to use [Backbone relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) instead of nested models (it automatically handles toJSON so you won't have to think about it).